# How to make sidebar buttons padding and margin aligned?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align buttons inside sidebar menu but somewhere i m making mistake it always stays to right , not good in css any idea , How can i make sidebar menu aligned or any better suggetion to apply css on sidebar menu will be appreciated ?

sideBar.html

```
<div class="sideBarMenu" ng-show="showMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger  btn-lg" ng-click="recordLogs()" ng-disabled="disabledRecBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record" title="start recording"></span></button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="stopLogs()" ng-disabled="disabledStopBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" title="stop recording"></span></button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" ng-click="searchLogs()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" title="search logs in bowser"></span></button>-->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info  btn-lg" ng-click="serverFiles()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" title="download server logged files"></span></button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

main.css

```
.sideBarMenu {
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    right:65px;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    background-color: grey;
}
.sideBarMenu ul li {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    list-style: none;
}
.sideBarMenu ul {
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
.sideBarMenu {
  height:300px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:35px;
  right:65px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  background-color: grey;
 }
 .sideBarMenu ul{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;

.sideBarMenu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}
.sideBarMenu ul li button {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #ccc;
 }
```

You can change the padding and margin as per your requirement.

Comment: is it possible to add kind of break tag e.g <hr> after each list item using css , i would like to show like a row

Comment: you mean bottom border for each li?

Comment: border is only showing in the middle under each list item how can we make it left to right complete

Comment: please try now.

Comment: border added to button

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: is the issue fixed?